# "Visitors to the zoo are asked not to... the lions." (tease or nag?)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I'm solving now tests in English and one of the sentences is:

> "Visitors to the zoo are asked not to... the lions."

The options for the missed part are:

a) bite

b) fret

c) nag

d) tease

And according to the key of the book the correct answer is d (tease). I don't understand why it can not be c ([nag](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nag)) as well. What makes option d more accurate than option c?

In addition, I don't understand the usage of the preposition "**to**" in this sentence. Should it not be "Visitors **in** the zoo are asked not to tease the lions"?

Comment: Could you add a definition of *nag* that fits your context? Also it could be "to the zoo" (where you went) or "in/at the zoo" (where you are).

Comment: Yes, of course. From Merriam Webster: 
Simple Definition of nag
: to annoy (someone) by often complaining about his or her behavior, appearance, etc.
: to annoy (someone) with repeated questions, requests, or orders
: to cause (someone) to feel annoyed or worried for a long period of time

Comment: OK, then which one(s) would apply to interactions between humans and zoo animals? *someone* (used here as the object of the action) generally refers to humans. So human-human would be *nagging* , but not human-animal.

Comment: ok, now I understand. But actually I was mistaken based on my language dictionary whih translates both of them in the same way. Now I got it. Thanks.

Comment: It is not advisable, under any circumstances, to do _any_ of these things to the lions. (The idiot who wrote your test confuses _correct_ with _best._ **None** of the options is incorrect in any way.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Yes, but I'd say that the formal passive form implies this is a sign or command from the zoo. I can't imagine a zoo putting up a warning sign not to bite the lions (unless they had already been sued for this begin absent ;-) )

Comment: This sign has been around the interweb for a while http://www.angmohdan.com/dont-badger-harry/

Comment: Toss that dictionary. Teasing and nagging have very different goals and behaviors.

Comment: The (World Famous) San Diego Zoo has a very amusing sign posted throughout: "Please do not annoy, torment, pester, plague, molest, worry, badger, harry, harass, heckle, persecute, irk, bullyrag, vex, disquiet, grate, beset, bother, tease, nettle, tantalize, or ruffle the animals."  I note that only one of the provided options (tease) is on that list.

Comment: @Ghotir Yes, but the original sign has a missing comma after *Badger* so that it actually says *Badger Harry*!

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, when a dictionary entry uses (someone), it can sometimes apply to non-humans, like objects or animals. (*See [this post.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107980/what-does-expense-mean-in-we-all-had-a-meal-at-the-airlines-expense)*)

This is not one of those cases. Nagging happens between people. The (stereo)typical example is of a wife *nagging* her husband specifically with questions and commands.  It does not really mean *to annoy* in a broad sense.
[image]

> Did you remember to take out the recycling? I thought I asked you to clean the bathroom? You said you’d quit smoking! ([Source.](http://www.chatelaine.com/health/sex-and-relationships/stop-nagging-six-tips-to-break-the-habit-and-improve-your-relationship/))

You can't really nag an animal. Instead you can *tease* them. 
[image]

When you [tease](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tease) an animal, you are annoying them or bothering them, often by making faces (above). This is usually done to provoke the animal. I'm sure you've seen kids do something similar.

As for *to*, I guess it is simply idiomatic. *Visitors to the zoo* do not have to be people inside the zoo, as far as I can tell. They can be people who will visit or regularly visit the zoo. *Visitors **in** the zoo* explicitly means people inside the zoo.

Comment: Does "nag" imply words being spoken?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh - Normally, yes. You could nag someone via a letter, or you could nag someone by leaving post-it notes everywhere, but nearly always the words would be spoken. And it definitely requires words, not actions.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words!

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries are all well and good, but all too often a term will not have the same *nuance* in a different language even if the dictionary definition is similar.  The best way to learn what a word *really* means is to see how it's used in context.

"Nag" does mean "harass", but in a kind of *familiar* way, as one family member to another.  You would not *nag* a lion -- you can only nag a *person*, and even then, usually only someone fairly close to you, who you see regularly over a long period of time. A mother can nag a child, or a child can nag a parent.  Sometimes a friend can nag another friend.

But any other relationship and we would probably use a different word.

Of the remaining choices, while it would be inadvisable to *bite* the lions, *tease* makes more sense in context. *Fret* doesn't fit at all.  As you say, *annoy* would also work, or *harass*, or *bother*, but these aren't choices.

As for "to", it's simply the correct preposition to use for these kind of activities.  We go *to* the zoo, or *to* the park, in the same way we go *to* a store or *to* the library.

Yes, it does make perfectly *logical* sense that the sign should make the request not to the visitors coming *to* the zoo, but rather the visitors who are already *in* the zoo.  Unfortunately, that's just not how it's usually phrased.

Some other examples:

> Visitors to the National Museum are asked not to touch the exhibits.
>
> Visitors to Hollywood should know that they are unlikely to see a movie star just walking around.
>
> Visitors to the gallery must have an appointment.