# Common informal way in English to describe an act of drinking that is done to "honor" a meeting?

Tags: phrase-request

Imagine a situation, in which three former schoolmates are getting together in a restaurant. They sit down at the table and one of them is saying, "So then, let's have a drink - just to mark our meeting tonight." Would this phrase sound strange in this kind of informal situation?

Does the word meeting sound too official here? Would the word "reunion" sound better? Or, perhaps, a completely another word?

And what about the verb "to mark"? Would "to celebrate" be a better choice?

So, in short, what's the common an informal way in English to describe an act of drinking that is done to "honor" a meeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let's have a drink" sounds fine. You could also say [*let's raise a glass*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raise+a+glass+to):

> raise a/(one's) glass (to someone)
>   To wish someone happiness, success, good fortune, etc., by raising one's drink. I would like everyone to raise their glasses in honor of my father, who is retiring from this company that he helped build from the ground up. Now, please raise your glass to the newly married couple!

You might be interested in [*toast*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/toast) ("let's have a toast"), though it's not particularly informal:

> - toast noun (DRINK)
>     [ C ] a short speech in honor of someone or in celebration of something, followed by everyone present taking a drink: 
>     Ted raised his glass and proposed a toast "to absent friends."
> - toast verb [ T ] (TAKE DRINK)
>     to make a short speech and take a drink in honor of someone or in celebration of something:
>     At midnight, we toasted the New Year.
>     (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Can I also "raise a glass" to something (instead of someone)? For example, can I raise a glass to our achievement, to our beginning, to our reunion, to our meeting, etc.?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. However, I can imagine that there are some who disagree. When a dictionary says "someone/somebody", it does not necessarily mean that the usage only applies to people. Notice that the "airline" is not a "someone" in my answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107980/what-does-expense-mean-in-we-all-had-a-meal-at-the-airlines-expense/107981#107981).